# Validate image upload unobtrusively using Jquery validate for dynamic forms?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I've got an image upload that is created on a dynamic form. I am trying to make it so that I can validate that the file uploaded is an actual image, and do this unobtrusively. I've read about the .rules() settings and using the accept property, but that requires you to input a field name (http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/accept). Since the forms are dynamic I won't know the field name. My view that generates the upload input looks like this:

```
 <input type="file" size="20" name="@(Model.FormItem.Id + "-image")" id="@(Model.FormItem.Id + "-image")" />
```

So all my file inputs have an "-image" suffix. Is there a way to add a rule using a jquery selector for the validator rules instead of using a specific field name??

**EDIT** Alright it's clear that I am not explaining what the problem is well. Perhaps the solution is so simple and somehow I just missed it. I know how to use jQuery selectors, but from the examples I have seen of the `rules` syntax you have to supply a static field name for the rules. How can I assign validate rules to a selector instead of a static field name??

So right now this is what I have :

```
 var validatorData = $('#items-form').data('validator');

        $.extend(validatorData.settings, {
            rules: {
                static_field_name: { accept: "jpg|png" }
            },
            messages: {
                static_field_name_message: "The file must be an image."
            }
        });
```

Which won't work, nor does (obviously) if I replace `static_field_name` with the proper selector `$('input[name$="-image"]')`. So how do I do this?

Comment: It should not matter if your `name` attribute is generated since you have that `-image` suffix, you can probably get them like `$(input[name$="-image"])`

Comment: I know how I would select the image uplaods, but how would I add that rule then? From what I have seen, adding the rules requires a static field name, you can't add a rule to a jQuery selector can you? The link I put in the question shows what I am referring to, is there another way to add rules?

Comment: Try with [setDefaults](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/setDefaults#defaults) to add/change rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how to do this using `.addClassRules()` like so:

```
$.validator.addClassRules("image-upload", {
       accept: "jpg|png|gif"
});
```

Then just apply class `image-upload` to the input. However, to also make it work unobtrusively I had to refactor the rules to get a custom message (http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Reference#Refactoring_rules):

```
$.validator.addMethod("acceptImageTypes", $.validator.methods.accept,
  "Selected File must be an image.");

        $.validator.addClassRules("image-upload", {
            acceptImageTypes: "jpg|png|gif"
        });
```

Then change my markup to:

```
<label>Image</label>
<input type="file" size="20" data-val="true" class="image-upload" name="@(Model.FormItem.Id + "-image")" id="@(Model.FormItem.Id + "-image")" />
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="@(Model.FormItem.Id + "-image")" data-valmsg-replace="true">File must be an image.</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 possible ways to solve this:

1) Using jQuery's .children() or $("#parent input:first") or $("input[type=file]:last") selectors so that your input doesn't require a static name.

2) Use a regex expression for your jQuery selector if you have any sort of pattern in the dynamic names given:

a) jquery way: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/

b) Or full regex way: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/

That should be the hard part. Then you can add your rules like you would normally.

Answer (score 0):

Of course your answer works, I'm adding this as a slightly different way to skin the same cat.

In the c# code section of the cshtml page:

```
//only allow these file types for upload
var allowedUploadExtensions = ".CSV|.DOC|.DOCX|.JPG|.JPEG|.PDF|.XLS|.XLSX|.TIF|.TIFF";    
var acceptMessage = allowedUploadExtensions.Replace("|", ",");
```

In your $(document)ready function:

```
            $.validator.addMethod('isValidFileExtension', function (value, element) {
            if (value == '')
                return true;  //data-val-required will catch lack of value.
            var extension = value.substr((value.lastIndexOf('.'))).toUpperCase();
            var validFileExtensions = new String('@allowedUploadExtensions').toUpperCase().split('|');
            return $.inArray(extension, validFileExtensions) > -1;
        });

        $('.file-upload').rules('add', { isValidFileExtension: true, messages: { isValidFileExtension: 'Invalid file extension, valid extensions are @acceptMessage'} });
```

and then in your markup:

```
<input type="file" name="UploadedFile" id="UploadedFile" 
                    class="file-upload"
                    data-val="true" 
                    data-val-required="Please select a document to upload."/>
```